# Tell Mail.app to check for new mail with MacRuby

Tags: ruby, applescript, macruby

I want to use MacRuby to tell Mail.app to check for new email. But I cannot figure out how to go about this after I get an application reference using SBApplication.

I have the following simple script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/macruby
framework 'ScriptingBridge'

mail = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier("com.apple.mail")
# mail.check_for_new_mail?
```

Basically I want to do the following AppleScript in MacRuby:

```
tell application "Mail"
    check for new mail
end tell
```

Yes, I can just use the AppleScript. But I much prefer Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/macruby
framework 'ScriptingBridge'

mail = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier("com.apple.mail")
mail.accounts.each {|account| mail.checkForNewMailFor(account) }
```

**tip**: use `puts (mail.methods(true,true) - Object.new.methods)` which returns available cocoa only methods list for object and ancestors

Comment: `mail.accounts.map`? Shouldn't that be `mail.accounts.each`?

Comment: @Sean: Great tip for getting the Cocoa only methods too. Cheers!